# iframe transport isn't transferring any data

Tags: php, jquery-file-upload, jquery-iframe-transport

I'm using [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) with [jQuery-Iframe-Transport](http://cmlenz.github.com/jquery-iframe-transport/) to try to get support for older versions of IE.

I've set the [`forceIframeTransport`](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) option to `true` so that it behaves more or less the same way in all browsers, but I don't seem to get any data back on the server-side regardless of browser when it uses the iframe transport.

I've spat out the request headers server-side and I get back:

```
array(
    Host => "*******"
    Connection => "keep-alive"
    Content-Length => "0"
    Accept => "*/*"
    Origin => "**************"
    X-Requested-With => "XMLHttpRequest"
    User-Agent => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17"
    DNT => "1"
    Referer => "***********"
    Accept-Encoding => "gzip,deflate,sdch"
    Accept-Language => "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
    Accept-Charset => "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3"
    Cookie => "*********"
)
```

[`*****`s indicated bleeped out info; you don't need that ;)]

Which look OK, but `$_REQUEST` is empty (i.e., `array()`), and the input buffer is empty too:

```
$handle = fopen('php://input', 'r');

$file_data = '';

while(($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    $file_data .= $buffer;
}

fclose($handle); // $file_data = '';
```

This all worked fine when I wasn't using the iframe-transport but I need IE support... does anyone have any experience with transmitting files using iframes and might know why no data is coming through?

---

When I use [jQuery-File-Upload / js / jquery.iframe-transport.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js) and force iframe transport it works in Chrome, but the requests don't even make it to the server in IE.

When I use [jquery-iframe-transport / jquery.iframe-transport.js](https://github.com/cmlenz/jquery-iframe-transport/blob/master/jquery.iframe-transport.js) and force iframe transport it breaks in Chrome, but that's fine because Chrome supports proper XHR file transfers, *and* the requests at least hit the server in IE *but* no data comes through.

I've updated my script to support either transfer method:

```
if(empty($_FILES)) {
    $handle = fopen('php://input', 'r');

    $file_data = '';

    while(($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $file_data .= $buffer;
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    $file_data = file_get_contents($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]);
}
```

But again, I still can't seem to get any data in IE regardless of what I do.

When I say "IE", I'm specifically testing in IE 8 right now. I need support back to 7 though. [This guy](http://cmlenz.github.com/jquery-iframe-transport/) claims support all the way back to IE 6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After many hours, I've finally tracked down the issue.

First, you need to use the transport plugin that comes [bundled with jQuery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js) because it was made for it ;) I'm not quite sure why the other one got a step further, but I'll get to that in a minute.

I noticed in IE that I was getting an "access is denied" JavaScript error somewhere in the core jquery library. From what I read online this usually happens when you try to submit to a URL at a different domain, which I wasn't doing, so I dismissed it.

I was comparing what the 2 different transport scripts did differently, when I came to a line that said `form.submit()` in one version, and `form[0].submit()` in the other. So I tried adding the `[0]` and then noticed the "access has denied" error changed to point to that line. So clearly, it didn't like where I was submitting the files to.

I double checked the `form.action` and the URL still looked fine. Through some [Google-fu](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/999) I discovered that you can also get this error if the event does not originate from the original/native file input element.

I had replaced the native input with a fancy one and then triggered a "fake" 'click' event on the hidden native input. This it didn't like.

Took out my fake upload button and plopped the native one (`<input type="file"/>` fyi) back in, and now everything works like a charm in all browsers. Huzzah!

Comment: Scrambled through a lot of sites looking for other IE/9 issues with jQuery file upload. After searching for `iframe transport ie8 not working` I found this - you saved the day! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth ...

I was working with jQuery v1.9.1 doing virus scanning on files synchronously before files are uploaded to the server. If the file had a virus, we WERE returning a HTTP 400, and HTTP 200 if not virus.

The HTTP 400 response caused the IE8 "Access Denied" result.

**When I changed server reponse from 400 to 401, the UI worked perfectly.**

Again, "For What It's Worth."