# Upload a txt to Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3

I am using the s3 sdk to upload a string (which will be change into a txt file). 
It is ok using the sdk. But since the sdk is only available for new browser (eg: ie10+) I need to upload my file with another way (for old browser)

For image file I use an input (type file) and a form for the upload

```
<form id="urlform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="upload_target" class="inline">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{$parent.keyurl}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="{{$parent.awSAccessKeyIdUrl}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="{{$parent.redirectionUrl}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-filename" value="{{$parent.filenameurl}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="{{$parent.policyurl}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="{{$parent.signatureurl}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-security-token" value="{{$parent.urlSessionToken}}">
    <div>
        <label>
        </label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="urlfileinput">
    </div>
</form>
```

this solution only works with input type file .

For security reason I can't change the value of the input with jquery.

Is there another way to upload text (using the rest api perhaps) ?

Comment: This could eventually help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882713/iframe-transport-isnt-transferring-any-data

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how you want the upload to behave, from the user's point of view? Why are you trying to change the value of the file input with jQuery?

Comment: Why don't you try to execute an AJAX request to server code realize the upload? It will improve the security, because really will hide the key and others options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. 
To upload a text I had to use an  inside the form with a the name "file".

```
<form id="disclaimerform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="upload_target" class="inline">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{keydisclaimer}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="{{awSAccessKeyId}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="{{redirection}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-filename" value="{{disclaimerfilename}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-security-token" value="{{session_token}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="{{policy}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="{{signature}}">
    <div>
        <label></label>
        <textarea style="opacity:0;" name="file" id="disclaimerinput"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious as to why you're using a URL form to submit this to Amazon...  This is hugely insecure since you're giving out your AWS Access Key to everyone.  First, you need to look into using the [Amazon SDK for Javascript](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforbrowser/), which should work easy enough with Angular as a dependency.

Next, you need to look into doing [CORS on your S3 Bucket (cross domain resource sharing)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTcors.html) so that you can in fact 'upload' something on S3 from anywhere without the need for authentication (be careful with this since *everyone* will have access to it and can upload anything, and if you don't configure it properly, can give access to other things like delete).

Lastly, you simply need to use the SDK's [AWS.S3().putObject()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) function to upload whatever you need to your public S3 bucket.

Comment: There is nothing insecure about giving out your access key.  The access key is not meant to be private.  The secret key is, however.  Based on the code in the question, the requests are apparently being signed with the secret/private key, which is expected and correct.

Comment: Also CORS, has nothing to do with authentication.  You can set CORS rules on your bucket and still expect requests to be authenticated so that only users you allow can upload to your bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formdata to send the file.

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("key", "{{$parent.keyurl}}");
formData.append("acl", 'public-read');
formData.append("AWSAccessKeyId", '{{$parent.awSAccessKeyIdUrl}}');
formData.append("success_action_redirect", '{{$parent.redirectionUrl}}');
.........
// JavaScript file-like object...
var blob = new Blob('testSample', { type: "text/xml"});
 formData.append("file", blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "upload_target");
request.send(formData);
```

Comment: What does "upload_target" mean? also I think it might be var blob = new Blob(['testSample'], { type: "text/xml"});

Comment: "upload_target" is the link to which you upload the file and 'testSample' is the text content for the generated document