# jQuery File Upload not using XHR or IFrame

Tags: jquery, file, upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have an upload solution using a setup similar to [this one](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Upload-directly-to-S3) where people can drag a file onto the page and have it upload to S3.

However, I'm hitting an issue with XHR/Iframe upload.  Essentially, if I leave out `forceIframeTransport` the file will get uploaded to S3 successfully, but the entire page ends up on S3, as that's where the form has submitted to.

When I include `forceIframeTransport` set to `true`, nothing happens.  There are no exceptions in the console, nothing happening on the server.

I have included `jquery.iframe-transport`, `jquery.ui.widget` and `jquery.fileupload` in the page, in that order.

Comment: Did you check console errors ?

Comment: not enough info, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code posted, it is hard to tell, but perhaps it is similar to this issue [iframe transport isn't transferring any data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882713/iframe-transport-isnt-transferring-any-data)

They were using a "fancy" button instead of a regular one and mocking up the onclick.

Post your code, and you might get better answers, or if it is the same as that link you sent, then let us know it is the exact same as that one.  Still, it is always good to see the code.